# I'm having a hard time installing Google Chrome on 16.04 LTS, please help?

Tags: google-chrome

I downloaded 64 bit version of google chrome from their website and tried to install it and this is what i get every time.
when i try to install libappindicator1 it says that is depends on libindicator7, when i try to install this it says depends on libappindicator1.

I am still relatively new to this and don't know all that much, any help is very much appreciated.

```
Inspiron-5520:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 178239 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (50.0.2661.86-1) over (50.0.2661.86-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

this is what i get when i try to install libappindicator1.

```
Inspiron-5520:~$ sudo apt-get -f install libappindicator1
[sudo] password for nick: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libappindicator1 : Depends: libindicator7 (>= 0.4.90) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

this is what i get when i try to install libindicator7.

```
Inspiron-5520:~$ sudo apt-get -f install libindicator7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you tried what it suggests to do to run `sudo apt-get -f install` with no other things listed after `install`?

Comment: when i run that i get this. what does it mean when it is asking are you root? ~~~~ Inspiron-5520:~$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: Correct.  You need to run the command with `sudo` in front of it.  `sudo` means to run the command as an elevated user or `root`.

Comment: That worked, thank you for your help, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, get the same thing, running `sudo apt-get -f install` fixes it.  Don't put the package name, apt-get will figure it out.  Also had a similar experience with Dropbox, but it was not a big deal either to fix (same method)

Comment: when i run that i get this. what does it mean when it is asking are you root? ~~~~ Inspiron-5520:~$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: You are not running apt-get as root or with sudo.  Try either putting sudo infront of the command like I did above, or running the command after switching to root (`su<enter>`)